# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable - Python beginner

Tags: python

I'm a fairly new programmer and I started learning Python. I've given myself the task of programming a text-based RPG with a kind of round-based fighting like Pokémon or the older Final Fantasy games. Right now I'm working on the battle mechanics, but I ran into an error which I couldn't fix. When I call the 'battle' function in my main I always get the error: 'TypeError: 'int' object is not callable'. I'd be happy if you could help me with this one, like I said, I'm still very new to programming.

My error-Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Doku\Python310\Scripts\text_adventure.py", line 169, in <module>
    battle(main.health, main.attack, main.defence, enemy.health, enemy.attack, enemy.defence, main, enemy)   File "C:\Doku\Python310\Scripts\text_adventure.py", line 106, in battle
    x = player.attack(enemy.health) TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

line 169

```
#call battle function with the stats of my main character and an enemy
battle(main.health, main.attack, main.defence, enemy.health, enemy.attack, enemy.defence, main, enemy)
```

line 103-112

```
#choose between attack and special attack - error occurs with both descisions the same way
while True:
    desc = choose()
    if desc == 'A' or desc == 'a':  
        x = player.attack(enemy)
        y = player.check_battle()
        break
    elif desc == 'B' or desc == 'b':
            player.specialmove(enemy)
            player.check_battle()
            break
```

my choose function:

```
#couldn't run it without it, don't know why
def choose():
    desc = input()
    return desc
```

my main (shortened)character class:

```
class Main:
    
    #init
    def __init__(self, Mhealth, Mattack, Mdefence):
        self.health = Mhealth
        self.attack = Mattack
        self.defence = Mdefence
        self.multiplier = 1.00

    #attacks
    def attack(self, enemy):
        x = enemy.health - (self.attack-enemy.defence)
        enemy.setHealth(x)
        
    def specialmove(self, enemy):
        enemy.health -= round((self.attack*1.5)-enemy.defence)

    def movelist(self): 
        moves = ['A - Attack', 'B - Special']
        return moves
```

my enemy class is built the same way

Comment: Please use a **Minimal Example**

Comment: `attack` is both a field and the name of a function, don't use the same name for both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self.attack` is an integer. You set it in `__init__` part of the class. Rename either the attack function or this number.